# Contact Form 7 - Message with a URL will always fail

Tags: plugin-contact-form-7

When submitting a message from Contact Form 7 at https://www.datanumen.com/contact/, if I include a URL in the form, then the submission will always fail, see below:

[image]

I have tried to disable all plugins except Contact Form 7, and switch to the default WP theme, but all not working.

I have asked [Contact Form 7 support](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/message-with-a-url-will-always-fail/), but they also cannot help.

I doubt there is an internal anti-spam mechanism of WP email system, because in the past, when I use emails from free domains, such as @gmail.com, @outlook.com, @yahoo.com, and the email is sent to a different domain that the one hosting contact form 7, then I will also [get an error](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/using-reply-to-your-email-will-cause-error/#post-16855710).

I just wonder if there is an internal log or other way to find and fix the issue?

**Update**

I install WP Mail SMTP and configure SMTP settings. Then I send a test email via WP Mail SMTP. It is OK. However, when I try to use the contact form, it fails again.

I install WP Mail Logging. Then if I try to use the contact form WITHOUT a URL, then the email will be sent properly and appear in the log. However, if I include a URL in the contact form, then it will fail again and the failed email does NOT appear in WP Mail Logging list at all, so I cannot diagnose it, either.

Comment: you say "I doubt there is an internal anti-spam mechanism of WP email system" - I say that it's highly likely you have an issue with email sending on your WordPress site. Use a dedicated service for this -they are cheap/nearly free.  More info: https://getshieldsecurity.com/blog/wordpress-email-deliverability/

Comment: @PaulG., actually I have setup to include SFP, DKIM, etc. records for our domain. So if I sent emails via Outlook, or other tools, everything is OK. However, since our website needs a online contact form and we have to use WordPress to send the email. The problem is how WordPress send emails is completely mysterious to me. There are no settings or configurations for it. Normally it should contain a SMTP authorization, but I find no way to set it.

Comment: Please have a read of the article. Using WordPress to send an email is basically using your server - and if you didn't configure this yourself, then it's a black box and no amount of debugging will solve it for you. The solution is really, really... really simple - use a dedicated 3rd party. There are loads of them with WordPress plugins.

Comment: @PaulG., I see the article mention mailgun. But I don't want to use third-party mail service.  It is said another article will introduce how to configure in WP itself. But I cannot find that one.

Comment: Okay, best of luck!

Comment: I'd add trace to the CF7 mail sending flow using error_log(): add logs at the point the form is submitted, and at the point that it calls wp_mail(), and at any obvious decision points in between. Then look at your site's error log to see where the flow is stopping.

Comment: @Rup, Thank you. It is a shortcode in the page. How to add the error_log()? Add to the source code of CF7?